# SMS sent from j2me not recieved by non-java phones like android and gsm modem

Tags: java-me, sms, gsm, wma, pdu

I need to send a pattern like "username,password,0,1,1,1,0,1,0" using sms from j2me app to a gsm modem that is not in my control. It is used to reserve foods.

If anyone send a sms to provided number of the gsm modem using any mobile phone normally (like how you send sms to anyone), it will reply an answer.

My problem is sms sent from my j2me app is received by any java phone, but the gsm modem doesn't get it (as I didn't receive the reply and the food is not reserved). Same as gsm modem android phones don't receive my sms.

I used the typical j2me libraries to send sms. I tried TextMessage, no luck. Then I tried BinaryMessage, it didn't received by gsm modem but android received it!

Another thing is that I couldn't find any complete source, documentation or examples about sms pdu. Is the binary payLoad all the full sms format sent using BinaryMessage?

At the end I would now is it possible to send normal text sms using BinaryMessage? Any examples?

Thanks in advance.
Regards, Ali.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to send sms by AT commands, compose message and send it sending by commands: (AT+CMGS, AT+CMSS)

[Here is tutorial for it](http://www.developershome.com/sms/operatingMode2.asp)

At the bottom you have full list of topics about AT commands and SMS sending.

For using AT commands [tutorial for AT commands in java me](http://www.wirelessdevnet.com/channels/java/features/j2me_http.phtml)